# laravel - validate complex conditions on request inputs

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a input with type='file'. I want this input to have a validation rule 
based on its content. For example, it has specific content structure and if it doesn't, `$validator->fails()` returns true. I don't want to do that inside controller and make it ugly. What is the best and cleanest approach to do that?
I mean by "cleanest" the best place(directory/class/method) that the logic has should be located.
Thanks

Comment: Did you know that Laravel has a Slack?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to create a   [form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests). Form requests are custom request classes that contain validation logic.

Laravel then automatically passes the user's input into the request before parse through the POST route, meaning our validation can now be moved entirely into **FormRequest** objects and out of our controllers and models.